# Undefined property in model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

User model:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token', 'role_id',
    ];

    protected $appends = [
        'role',
    ];

    public function getRoleAttribute()
    {
        return $this->role->name;
    }

    /**
     * User role.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function role()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Role');
    }
}
```

I wan't to show the name of a role instead the role id.

But it says:

*ErrorException in User.php line 38:
Undefined property: App\User::$role*

The roles table contains an **id** and **name**

The users table contains a **role_id**

**Edit:**

When i try `return $this->role()->name;` it gives me a:

*ErrorException in User.php line 38:
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::$name*

But i check for role and that works...

```
/**
 * Check if the user is an admin.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function isAdmin()
{
    if ($this->role->name == 'admin') {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is because you have **role** attribute and **role** relation, try to rename one of them, and it will work with `return $this->role->name;`

Comment: Wow you are the best, i kinda made sense.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the relation, not property:

```
{{ $user->role()->name }}
```

Comment: Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::$name